# Generate authentication token and use it throughout the session in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a scenario where I am hitting the keyCloak requests and using the token as a header in the other HTTP requests.

My problem is for 100 users it is generating 100 tokens so I am looking for the solution in which keyCloak request is hit only once and the token is used throughout the performance run.

Sample code snippet for the reference:

```
   scenario("CMS service")
   .exec(KeycloakToken.request(conf))
   .exec(getOffers.request(conf))
   .exec(offerById.request(conf))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use feeder https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/ .

1) Create feeder

```
val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("token" -> "dG9rZW4="))
```

2) Add feeder to scenario

```
 scenario("CMS service")
   .feed(feeder)
   .exec(...)
```

3) Pass value via Gatling EL https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el

In your http request add token

```
http(...)
    .post(...)
    .header("your token header", "${token}")
```